# Using sshfs with Synology NAS results in connection reset

Tags: mount, sshfs, nas, synology

I use sshfs to mount a folder from a synology NAS (DS216+) locally to my Ubuntu machine. The command I use is

`sshfs -o uid=1234,gid=1234,allow_other,default_permissions mysynology.box.com: /mnt/local.folder`

The mount is (initially) succesful, in the sense that I can `cd` to the mounted folder from my ubuntu box, create files, etc.

However, when I try to use the mount for something actually useful, like to create/move/copy larger files in batch, or create/manipulate a git repo, the sshfs mount is reset, and I get a `failed: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)` error when I try to use the mount point from then on.

Note that, I have used the same command to mount folders by sshfs from two other, different unix boxes, other than the Synology box, with absolutely no problem.

What could be the cause / remedy to this problem?

Comment: Did you add your ubuntu pub key to your nas? Perhaps it connects for doing key negotiation but that doesn't happen so it closes the connection soon after. Given you did install a pub key, I would check security settings on the nas and look for log files to get a clue.